# t-sql string unique ID (Northwind database)

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, unique-id

I've been trying to get this right for some time now with no use.

I have a table in mssql database and I want to insert new row using stored procedure

```
CREATE TABLE "Customers" (
"CustomerID" NCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
"CompanyName" NVARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
"ContactName" NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
"ContactTitle" NVARCHAR(30) NULL,
"Address" NVARCHAR(60) NULL,
"City" NVARCHAR(15) NULL,
"Region" NVARCHAR(15) NULL,
"PostalCode" NVARCHAR(10) NULL,
"Country" NVARCHAR(15) NULL,
"Phone" NVARCHAR(24) NULL,
"Fax" NVARCHAR(24) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY ("CustomerID")
);
```

The problem is CustomerID field which contains unique string for each record (ALFKI, BERGS, BERGS, etc.)

I want to make a stored procedure which will insert a row with new data and create an unique CustomerID. Build in functions are out of a question as I need the string to be 5 chars long.

I have a procedure which generates 5 chars ID as follows

```
begin

declare @chars char(26) = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
declare @i int = 0
declare @id varchar(max) = ''

while @i < 5
begin
        set @id = @id + substring(@chars, cast(ceiling(rand() * 26) as int), 1)

    set @i = @i + 1
end

Select (cast(@id as nvarchar(400)))

end
```

And the one that I tried to make work with no use. It is supposed to select an unique id (set @id = 'ANATR' is there on purpose to make it go into the loop

```
begin
declare @randID varchar(5) = ''
declare @selectID varchar(20) = ''
declare @chars char(26) = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
declare @i int = 0
declare @id varchar(10) = ''

while @i < 5
begin
   set @id = @id + substring(@chars, cast(ceiling(rand() * 26) as int), 1)           
    set @i = @i + 1
end
select @id
set @id = 'ANATR'

SET @selectID = (SELECT CustomerID FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CustomerID = @id)


while @selectID <> 'NULL'
begin
    set @id = ''
    while @i < 5
        begin
            set @id = @id + substring(@chars, cast(ceiling(rand() * 26) as int), 1)           
            set @i = @i + 1
        end

    SET @selectID = (SELECT CustomerID FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE CustomerID = @id)   

    SELECT @id
end


end
```

Here is the insert procedure I have at the moment

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertCustomers]

(

@CustomerID nchar(5),

@CompanyName nvarchar(40),

@ContactName nvarchar(30) = NULL,

@ContactTitle nvarchar(30) = NULL,

@Address nvarchar(60) = NULL,

@City nvarchar(15) = NULL,

@Region nvarchar(15) = NULL,

@PostalCode nvarchar(10) = NULL,

@Country nvarchar(15) = NULL,

@Phone nvarchar(24) = NULL,

@Fax nvarchar(24) = NULL

)

AS

SET NOCOUNT OFF;

 INSERT INTO [dbo].[Customers] ([CustomerID], [CompanyName], [ContactName], [ContactTitle], [Address], [City], [Region], [PostalCode], [Country], [Phone], [Fax]) VALUES (@CustomerID, @CompanyName, @ContactName, @ContactTitle, @Address, @City, @Region, @PostalCode, @Country, @Phone, @Fax);
```

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I believe you can do something like this to make sure you all get a unique id

```
begin

declare @chars char(26) = 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
declare @i int = 0
declare @id varchar(max) = ''


while (1=1)
begin
        set @id = @id + substring(@chars, cast(ceiling(rand() * 26) as int), 1)

    set @i = @i + 1

   IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE CustomerID = @id) AND LEN(@id) = 5)
      BREAK
   ELSE
      CONTINUE
end

Select (cast(@id as nvarchar(400)))

end
```

Set the while condition to be always true and break out of while loop only when both of your requirements are TRUE i.e `Length of new ID is 5` and it `does not exist in the customers table already`.

Comment: As the Customers table gets larger, the cost of reading all of those values to check for a duplicate goes up, as do your odds of hitting a duplicate. See the links in my answer to understand why this solution simply won't scale.

Comment: @Bartosz if your teacher likes this solution, you should quit the course and ask for your money back. This is the type of solution a database person simply shouldn't be satisfied with. Make sure you give your teacher a link to this question - if you don't want to learn from it maybe you should give them a chance to...

Comment: @AaronBertrand I agree with you and I laughed my head off when I read your comment 'if your teacher likes this solution, you should quit the course and ask for your money back' lollll

Comment: It is a mandatory course at the university so I can't have my money back, I didn'y pay for it :D
anyways, @AaronBertrand this project was made in a hurry just to pass the course, no real benefit from that. The solution can be viewed here if you are interested [link](http://bartosz.jakubowiak.pl/)

Answer (score 8):

The main problem here is that the incremental cost of detecting collisions from the generated string, and try again, increases as you generate more and more strings (since you have to read *all* of those strings to make sure you didn't generate a duplicate). At the same time, the odds of hitting a duplicate goes up, meaning the bigger the table gets, the slower this process will get.

Why do you need to generate the unique string at runtime? Build them all in advance. [This article](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3055/generating-random-numbers-in-sql-server-without-collisions/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) and [this post](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2013/09/t-sql-queries/random-collisions) are about random numbers, but the basic concept is the same. You build up a set of unique strings and pull one off the stack when you need one. Your chance of collisions stays constant at 0% throughout the lifetime of the application (provided you build up a stack of enough unique values). Pay for the cost of collisions up front, in your own setup, instead of incrementally over time (and at the cost of a user waiting for those attempts to finally yield a unique number).

This will generate 100,000 unique 5-character strings, at the low, one-time cost of about 1 second (on my machine):

```sql
;WITH 
 a(a) AS 
 (
   SELECT TOP (26) number + 65 FROM master..spt_values 
   WHERE type = N'P' ORDER BY number
 ),
 b(a) AS 
 (
   SELECT TOP (10) a FROM a ORDER BY NEWID()
 )
SELECT DISTINCT CHAR(b.a) + CHAR(c.a) + CHAR(d.a) + CHAR(e.a) + CHAR(f.a)
FROM b, b AS c, b AS d, b AS e, b AS f;
```

That's not enough? You can generate about 1.12 million unique values by changing `TOP (10)` to `TOP (20)`. This took 18 seconds. Still not enough? `TOP (24)` will give you just under 8 million in about 2 minutes. It will get exponentially more expensive as you generate more strings, because that `DISTINCT` has to do the same duplicate checking you want to do *every* **single** time you add a customer.

So, create a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.StringStack
(
  ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
  String CHAR(5) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Insert that set:

```sql
;WITH 
 a(a) AS 
 (
   SELECT TOP (26) number + 65 FROM master..spt_values 
   WHERE type = N'P' ORDER BY number
 ),
 b(a) AS 
 (
   SELECT TOP (10) a FROM a ORDER BY NEWID()
 )
INSERT dbo.StringStack(String)
SELECT DISTINCT CHAR(b.a) + CHAR(c.a) + CHAR(d.a) + CHAR(e.a) + CHAR(f.a)
FROM b, b AS c, b AS d, b AS e, b AS f;
```

And then just create a procedure that pops one off the stack when you need it:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.AddCustomer
  @CustomerName VARCHAR(64) /* , other params */
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  
  DELETE TOP (1) dbo.StringStack
    OUTPUT deleted.String, @CustomerName /* , other params */
    INTO dbo.Customers(CustomerID, CustomerName /*, ...other columns... */);
END
GO
```

No silly looping, no needing to check if the `CustomerID` you generated just exists, etc. The only additional thing you'll want to build is some type of check that notifies you when you're getting low.

As an aside, these are terrible identifiers for a CustomerID. What is wrong with a sequential surrogate key, like an IDENTITY column? How is a 5-digit random string with all this effort involved, any better than a unique number the system can generate for you much more easily?

Comment: I like this a lot. 1 (sincere) question though, what does the performance look like on `SELECT` and then `DELETE` on that potentially million row single column `StringStack` table? Also any chance of DEADLOCKS if many instances of App are trying to do INSERTS around same time?

Comment: @Shiva the `DELETE TOP (1)` is going to do a clustered index seek to get the very first row available (and will pick the lowest ID value). There simply isn't a more efficient way to pick a single row from this table. As for deadlocks, highly unlikely. The most common deadlocks typically result from two different transactions trying to gain locks on two different objects in different order (there are others of course). In this case, it is one atomic statement. 500 people could try this at the same time, and they'll block but not deadlock (unless other transactions are involved).

Answer (score 3):

Muhammed Ali 's answer works, but will prove rather ressource intensive (especially when there aren't many combinations of 5 letters left to use) : your function uses the random generator, and it will take it a while to find a combination that isn't used, especially since it has a very limited memory of its previous results. 
This means it will try, and might give you something of the sort (exaggerating a bit) : BAGER the first time, then ANSWE the second time, then again BAGER the third time. You see you will lose a good amount of time with the generator giving you the same answer over and over again (especially over 12M possible combinations).

If you are looking for a fixed length ID (since you use NCHAR(5), I guess that's a good assumption), I would rather look into building a table that contains all the possible combinations, and pick one value of this table every time you need one. You would delete it once it got used, or mark it as used (which I would prefer, for reuseability reasons).

This leads to my final comment (which I cannot put as comment 'cause I don't have enough reputation) : why not use the IDENTITY function provided by MS-SQL ? This provides a much better handling of the Primary key generation...

Comment: yup, sorry about that, I didn't get your answer before posting mine ^^" And I would have +1 yours instead if I had the reputation to do so..

Comment: If it was up to me I would use int ID and auto increment but it is a task form my teacher who makes us do never-used-in-a-real-world tasks

Comment: @BartoszJakubowiak and did your teacher's course materials not give you any insight into how they want you to solve this problem? This site is for real-world programming problems, since we don't have the benefit (like you do) of knowing what your teacher has taught you and what type of solution they expect.\